# Recursion in return statement

Tags: c, function, recursion, data-structures, tree

Can somebody please explain me the execution of two recursive functions in return statement, like this

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};


struct node* newNode(int data)
{
    struct node* node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    node->data = data;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    return(node);
}

int size(struct node* node) 
{
    if (node==NULL) 
        return 0;
    else    


  return(size(node->left) + 1 + size(node->right));


}


int main()
{

    struct node *root = newNode(1);
    root->left        = newNode(2);
    root->right       = newNode(3);
    root->left->left  = newNode(4);
    root->left->right = newNode(5);   
    printf("Size of the tree is %d", size(root));  
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

How does the size() functions execute in return statement in this case, whether from left to right or from right to left! I want to know the flow of executing of both the functions.

Comment: would it be easier for you if you use `int s=size(node->left) + 1 + size(node->right); return s;`?

Comment: It certainly would be but I am more interested to know how does two recursive functions in return statement executes. Do they execute in parallel or in some way of left to right or right to left!

Comment: It will not be executed in parallel, as C is not a parallel language. Look at [Order of evaluation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order), and you will see that there is no guarantee which recursive function is first executed.

Comment: Functions do not execute in parallel. They may execute right to left, left to right, from the middle ourwards, or in any other order, but not in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion is driven by two concepts, propagating condition and terminating condition.

The condition (node == NULL) is a terminating condition to come out of recursion and size(node->left) + 1 + size(node->right) is propagating condition which propagates the left tree and right tree from root and subsequent nodes and adds 1 to size for the node itself.

To explain you fully we need to take a sample tree

```
                 3
          4               5
      1        2      9       8
```

Recursion goes like this for sample tree

```
size(3)
 = size(4) + size(5)       + 1
```

lets now see `size(4) = size(1) + size (2) + 1`
size(1) = size(NULL) + 1 = 0 + 1 = 1  (because 1 has no left and if node is NULL the function returns 0 -  terminating condition)
size(2) = size(NULL) + 1 = 0 + 1 = 1
thus size(4) is 3

In similar fashion size(5) will be 3 as well, thus
size(1) = 3+3+1 = 7 nodes in the tree

Thus execution is

```
size (3) 
size (4) + size (5) + 1
size (1) + size (2) + 1 + size(9) +size (8) + 1
size (NULL) + 1 +size (NULL) + 1  + 1 +size (NULL) + 1  +size (NULL) + 1  +1
```

final return being

```
return 0 + 1+ 0+1+1+0+1+0+1+1
```

return 7

Answer (score 0):

here is the sequence

```
size(root)
=size(root->left) + 1 + size(root->right)
=(size(root->left->left) + 1+ size(root->left->right)) + 1 + size(root->right)
=((size(root->left->left->left) + 1 + size(root->left->left->right)) + 1+ size(root->left->right)) + 1 + size(root->right)
=((0 + 1 + size(root->left->left->right)) + 1+ size(root->left->right)) + 1 + size(root->right)
=((0 + 1 + 0) + 1+ size(root->left->right)) + 1 + size(root->right)
=(1 + 1+ size(root->left->right)) + 1 + size(root->right)
=(1 + 1+ (size(root->left->right->left) +1+ size(root->left->right->right)) + 1 + size(root->right)
=(1 + 1+ (0 +1+ size(root->left->right->right)) + 1 + size(root->right)
=(1 + 1+ (0 +1+ 0)) + 1 + size(root->right)
=(1 + 1+ 1) + 1 + size(root->right)
=(3) + 1 + (size(root->right->left)+ 1 +size(root->right->right))
=(3) + 1 + (size(root->right->left->left)+ 1+ size(root->right->left->right))+ 1 +size(root->right->right))
=(3) + 1 + (0+ 1+ size(root->right->left->right))+ 1 +size(root->right->right))
=(3) + 1 + (0+ 1+ 0)+ 1 +size(root->right->right))
=(3) + 1 + (1)+ 1 +(size(root->right->right->left)+1+ size(root->right->right->right))
=(3) + 1 + (1)+ 1 +(0+1+ size(root->right->right->right))
=(3) + 1 + (1)+ 1 +(0+1+ 0)
=(3) + 1 + (1)+ 1 +(1)
=(3) + 1 + (3)
=7
```

Here is the code sequence:

```
//step 1
size(root)
{
    //node===root
    if (root==NULL)//no
        return 0;
    else
        return(size(root->left) + 1 + size(root->right));
        //it will call size(root->left)
       //after size(root->left) it will plus 1 then will call size(root->right)
}
//step 2
size(root->left)
{

    if (root->left==NULL)//no
        return 0;
    else
        return(size(root->left->left) + 1 + size(root->left->right));
}
//step 3
size(root->left->left)
{

    if (root->left->left==NULL)//no
        return 0;
    else
        return(size(root->left->left->left) + 1 + size(root->left->left->right));
}
//step 4
size(root->left->left-->left)
{

    if (root->left->left==NULL)//yes
        return 0;
    //it returns to step 3

}
//step 5 from step 3
size(root->left->left)
{

    if (root->left->left==NULL)//no
        return 0;
    else
        return(0 + 1 + size(root->left->left->right));
       //size(root->left->left->left==0
       //now it calls size(root->left->left->right)
}
//step 6 from step 5

size(root->left->left->right)
{

    if (root->left->left->right)//yes
        return 0;
    //it retuns to step 5
}
//step 7 from step 3
size(root->left->left)
{

    if (root->left->left==NULL)//no
        return 0;
    else
        return(0 + 1 + 0);//==1
       //size(root->left->left->right)==0
       //now it returns to 2
}
```

hope you understand the rest.